# Как при повторном запуске, открыть свернутое приложение?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При первом запуске приложения, оно сворачивается в трей. При повторном запуске приложения, отображается уведомление, что приложение уже запущено.

Подскажите, как, при повторном запуске открывать приложение из трея?

Код внутри Program.cs

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        bool onlyInstance;

        Mutex mtx = new Mutex(true, "MyApp", out onlyInstance);

        if (onlyInstance)
        {
            Application.Run(new FormMain());
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Приложение уже запущено", "Сообщение", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
    }
```

Не получается добавить такой код в Program.cs `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;` так как нужно вместо `this` указать главную форму. Не могу разобраться как это сделать.

Comment: Тем или иным способом нужно послать сообщение первому (свернутому) экземпляру приложения. Способы есть разные, посмотреть можно [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19147/5045688).

Answer (score 3):

Решение с использованием `Mutex` и `NamedPipe` (без использования `DllImport`):

```
using System;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "myApp"))
            {
                if (!mutex.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), false))
                {
                    using (NamedPipeClientStream stream = new NamedPipeClientStream("myApp"))
                    {
                        stream.Connect();
                        stream.WriteByte(100);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                using (NamedPipeServerStream stream = new NamedPipeServerStream("myApp"))
                {
                    Task.Run(() => WaitClientMessage(stream));
                    try { RunProgramm(); }
                    finally { mutex.ReleaseMutex(); }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void RunProgramm()
        {
            // Здесь нужно запустить программу
            Console.WriteLine("Started!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void WaitClientMessage(NamedPipeServerStream stream)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                stream.WaitForConnection();
                stream.ReadByte();
                // Здесь нужно активировать программу, показать окно или т.п.
                Console.WriteLine("Activate me!");
                stream.Disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: На линуксах под моно NamedPipe похоже не работает. Не проверяли? Прямо сейчас исключения нет под рукой.

Comment: Не, на линуксе .NET вообще не пробовал

Answer (score 1):

```
static class Program
{
    //для FindWindow, чтобы найти хендл нужного окна
    [DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
    private static extern int FindWindow(String ClassName, String WindowName);
    //SetForeground, чтоб активировать окно по хендлу
    [DllImportAttribute("User32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);

    /// <summary>
    /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        //поиск окна по заголовку
        int hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Form1");
        if (hWnd > 0) //нашли
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd); //активировали
        }
        else//не нашли
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Таким образом программа два раза запустится, не?

Comment: @arrowd вы правы, сейчас исправлю

Comment: @arrowd Исправил.

Comment: Спасибо, но код слишком сложный... первый вариант был более понятен, разве нельзя использовать `if` и `else` в прошлом коде?

Comment: Код очень простой. DllImportAttribute загружают функции из dll Windows, их понимать не надо, просто скопируйте. Далее функция FindWindow ищет уже существующее окно по заголовку. SetForegroundWindow вызывает существующее окно на передний план.

Comment: Способ рабочий, однако поиск окна по заголовку не надёжен.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Можно использовать System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName и попробовать найти, например, по названию программы. Вот тут описано: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?460402-C-General-How-do-I-activate-an-external-Window

Answer (score 1):

Когда запускаешь второе приложение, то оно запускается в отдельном процессе, и, соответственно, во втором процессе ты не имеешь прямую ссылку к объекту в первом процессе.

Чтобы поднять окно из первого процесса нужно использовать межпроцессорное взаимодействие WCF, NetRemoting и т.д. Но в данном случае есть практика регистрации своего сообщения с отсылкой его в Windows очередь. Для этого используется функция win32 `RegisterWindowMessage`.

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam);

        internal static int WM_SHOWFIRSTINSTANCE;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            const int HWND_BROADCAST = 0xffff;
            WM_SHOWFIRSTINSTANCE = RegisterWindowMessage("MY_Message");

             bool onlyInstance;

            Mutex mtx = new Mutex(true, "MyApp", out onlyInstance);

            if (onlyInstance)
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Приложение уже запущено", "Сообщение", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                PostMessage((IntPtr)HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SHOWFIRSTINSTANCE, IntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == Program.WM_SHOWFIRSTINSTANCE)
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                this.Show();
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Может лучше без сторонних библиотек?

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    bool onlyInstance;

    Mutex mtx = new Mutex(true, "MyApp", out onlyInstance);
    FormMain form = new FormMain();

    if (onlyInstance)
    {
        Application.Run(form);
    }
    else
    {
        form.Show();
        MessageBox.Show("Приложение уже запущено", "Сообщение", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
}
```

Comment: Это покажет _новую_ форму, а не прежнюю.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, действительно. Не знал. Спасибо