# C# WPF запрет запуска копий приложения

Tags: c#, wpf

как запретить запуск новых копий приложения? если оно уже запущено то фокус на окно или развернуть

Comment: Это делается через мьютексы, пример [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/522874/312041)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как при повторном запуске, открыть свернутое приложение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/665480/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: Зайди в свойства проекта и поставь одну галочку. Не помню какую, но на ней всё понятно написано, думаю найдёшь.

Comment: @SNoteBookSystem пишите пожалуйста более конкретные ответы а не "зайди туда не знаю куда". Я такого пункта в настройках проекта не нашел

Answer (score 0):

В вашем `App.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected Mutex Mutex;

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            Mutex = new Mutex(true, ResourceAssembly.GetName().Name);
            if (!Mutex.WaitOne())
            {
                Current.Shutdown();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                new MainWindow().Show();
                ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose;
            }
            base.OnStartup(e);
        }

        protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Mutex != null)
            {
                Mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }

            base.OnExit(e);
        }
    }
```

Если запускаемое окно указано в файле разметки 'App.xaml' в атрибуте `StartupUri`  то `new MainWindow().Show();` можно опустить

```
<Application
    x:Class="CPL3_workstation.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="/MVVM/Views/MainView.xaml"/>
```